# What are the threats we may face after convert windows classic to claim authentication SharePoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-addin

Recently I have migrated my test site from `windows classic` to `claim based authentication`. Before doing the same in production, how to check if my site collection is working fine?  What are the potential issues that we may face after changed authentication modelto `claims` from `classic`? The Site contains a number of groups, workflows etc.. Any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

One of the tasks you will need to do is "migrate" the users to claims. If you don't do this, your users will get an access denied. This can be achieved using the following code:

```
Convert-SPWebApplication -Identity "http://sharepoint.domain.com/sites/sitecoll" -To Claims -From LEGACY -RetainPermissions
```

** Sometimes I run this command more than once.

Another caveat that you may experience is if you have InfoPath forms that pass user info to a data connection. Expect them to break in the browser. This is because InfoPath does not utilize the Claims to Windows Token Service, and most data connections and databases cannot translate claims tokens. You will need to utilize the Secure Store Service in order to allow users to impersonate a permissive account to retrieve the data from the data connection. Using their own username will no longer be seamless.

EDIT: I would suggest creating a separate stand-alone SharePoint farm (if you don't have a test environment), copying the content database to this new farm, in order to test this before migrating to claims in production.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that the main areas you will want to consider are:

1. Standard browsing: test users can authenticate to SharePoint correctly in their browsers, and browse your sites. If you use multiple web applications or host named site collections make sure you test each of these. Make sure to test in each browser that your users may be using, IE, Chrome and Firefox may all behave differently (and even different versions of each may behave differently)
2. Office Integration: Test that your users can open and save office documents correctly. Make sure to test each Office version that you use against each browser. For e.g. Chrome and Office 2013 may work fine but Chrome and Office 2010 might not. Also, if you use SharePoint Designer make sure to test that too.
3. 3rd Party Integrations: Test any 3rd party tools that you have which may interact with SharePoint, for e.g. your backup software.
4. Custom integrations: Make sure to very thoroughly test any custom integrations that you have, such as custom applications or scripts which access SharePoint, any custom code running in SharePoint itself, any timer/scheduled tasks. In particular watch out for any solutions which may forward/impersonate a user's credentials, common examples might be PerformancePoint or other BI solutions, or using BDC/BCS to connect to other data sources.